# unable add required attribute to a ReactJS input component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I am attempting to add a required attribute to a react input component:

```
export default function UiInput() {
   render() {
   return (
    <input
     {...customAttributes}
     size={size ? size : null}
     value={inputValue}
     maxLength={maxLength}
     required={required}
    />
   )
```

and when I am calling my component like so,

```
<UiInput 
   required={required}
  />
```

I am not getting the red asterisk to render - not getting any errors when I pass in required to an input component, but no red asterisk is showing up, how can I make sure the asterisk renders for required inputs? Does ReactJS not support this?

Answer (score 5):

Remember that you are passing `required` down as a `prop` to `UiInput`.

The pattern you're using for your Component is a Stateless Functional Component, when you do this:

- `props` gets passed through as a parameter.
- You don't need to declare the `render()` method, just simply write your return statement.

You can declare your Component like so:

```
function UiInput(props) {
      return (
        <input
         size={props.size ? props.size : null}
         required={props.required}
        />
      )
    }
```

And render it like so:

```
<UiInput required="required" />
```

You can see a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/80128/). Please be aware that I did remove some `props` for the purpose of this demo.

Here's the Component rendered, please ignore the `data-reactroot` attribute.
[image]